# Docker-Cloud "own node" doesn't connect (ubuntu server)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-cloud

I've tried to connect my vps Server with the dockercloud-agent, but I am not able to get it running.

I've tried multiple Ubuntu-Server versions (14.05, 15.05, and 16.xx) 
docker is installed, the cloud.docker script execuded.

On startup I get "deploying" on the docker-cloud Dasboard, but it always fails. This is the log output:

```
Bringing your node to Docker Cloud...
Agent contacted! Checking whether docker has started in node...
Waiting for docker port to be open...
Docker port is open!
Waiting for docker server to be up...
[...]
Waiting for docker server to be up...
Instance has been removed from Docker Cloud
PLEASE NOTE: we have not shut down the underlying host as it was not created by Docker Cloud
ERROR: Unable to connect to the Docker daemon in 42xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.node.dockerapp.io. Please try to restart the Docker Cloud agent and contact support if the problem persists.

Reallocating containers in other nodes...
Reallocation done!
```

I've opened Ports:

```
TCP 6783
UDP 6783
TCP 2375
```

I've even tried to run it with disabled firewall.

what I've found out:

- The DockerAPI is not reachable (I made it reachable with this [article](https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2016/05/18/enabling-docker-remote-api-on-ubuntu-16-04/))
- After i execuded the dockercloud script it wasn't reachable anymore

Comment: Could you update your tuorial for the current version of `dockercloud-agent`? I don't get it working..

Comment: oh sorry I can't because I don't own a server anymore :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I got it working on Ubuntu Server 16.04

I first enabled the docker rest API:

- 1) open lib/systemd/system/docker.service
- 2) edit the line that starts with ExecStart to ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
- 3) reload daemon: systemctl daemon-reload
- 4) restart docker service: service docker restart
- 5) execute dockercloud-agend script.

Now it should work.